# Changing RPi version may lead to binary corruption?

Tags: raspbian, signal

Apologizes for the object, but I cannot easily summarize the scenario.
I created an sd-card based upon Raspbian Stretch Lite, with some customization. 
Then I cross-compiled Qt5.9 and copied the libraries to the target.

I used the mkspec for RPi 1, in order to get an executable compatibles with all models.

How I tested it:

1. prepared the sd-card, copied all the libraries and application files
2. inserted into RPi B+ and confirmed it works
3. turned off, inserted into RPi 2 and confirmed it works
4. turned off, inserted into RPi 3 and confirmed it works
5. turned off, inserted into RPi B+ (or RPi 2) **and now I receive a SIGILL** when creating a websocket!

Now my application works *only* on RPi 3!

Does running it in a newer model might affect compatibility on the previous ones?

Comment: You can perform a test and go to step 3 and then go back to 2, check if it works, and keep going up like this, to see if it change upon devices or not. (this might be helpful for others to resolve this)

Comment: I routinely use the same image in B+, Pi2 & Pi3 (also in B, Zero W, but not recently). They all work. If you have a problem it is something you have done (which is a mystery).

Comment: @Milliways the same image or the same sd-card? It's different!

Comment: both. i often image using SD Card copier to a smaller SD Card for older Pi but swap cards often between Pi. However you do it an image is a byte by byte copy, although I do customise to ensure a `hostname` which matches the target Pi and unique `PARTUUID`

Comment: Where did you get your cross-compiler?

Comment: linaro from https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools